# Discord Bot [VB.net] Check if message has a mentioned user

Tags: vb.net, bots, discord

```
Case "-move" 'The command 'n shizzle like that ;p
If message.serverpermission.Administrator = true then
Dim user = message.Message.MentionedUsers.FirstOrDefault()
Dim role = message.Server.FindRoles(arg, True).FirstOrDefault()
Await user.AddRoles(role) '!error on this line!
```

I want to check if the admin specified an user, if not, he will receive an error like ,,There is no one online with that name" or like ... ,,You need to specify/mention an user"
(Program returns an error if no one is mentioned&crashes;

> System.NullReferenceException; 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.')

If you could help me with this problem, thanks! ^^

Comment: On what line is the error thrown? You can use the [**Autos window**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx) and/or hover over the variables in the source code in order to determine what is marked as `Nothing`.

Comment: Await user.AddRoles(role)

Comment: Then either `user` or `role` is null because `FirstOrDefault()` returns `Nothing` (null, which is what `...OrDefault` means) if the collection is empty. Which one of them is null can be verified by previously mentioned methods.

Comment: Okay.. If you're telling me to check which is null, then that's not my problem, i know that the role/user is null but i want to display a message like ,,You need to specify an user". If you're hinting at something else, then sorry, i'm a bit nooby >.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the fix for the problem here;

```
If IsNothing(user) Then
Await message.Channel.SendMessage("You need to mention a user.")
else
if isnothing(role) then
Await message.Channel.SendMessage("That role is invalid.")
else
Await message.Channel.SendMessage("Success message here ;P")
end if
end if
```

Comment: Instead of `If IsNothing(...) Then` you should rather use `If ... Is Nothing Then`. Using the [**`IsNothing()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(v=vs.90).aspx) is a legacy way of doing it and should be [**avoided these days**](http://blog.reneorban.com/2011/12/vbnet-isnothing-vs-is-nothing.html).